# How to pass system variables to container job? (Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure-devops

In the container job of the azure pipeline, I am trying to start a container with a mount of the checked-out code in the working directory:

```
     container:
        image: dockerhub.io/myregistry/myimg:latest 
        options: --privileged --volume '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)':/mnt/data:ro
     steps:
     - script: printenv
```

How do I use the $System.DefaultWorkingDirectory variable so that I can mount the source code directory into the /mnt/data mounting point in the container?

I tried multiple ways, it always complaining using invalid characters.

```
Error response from daemon: create '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)': "'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
```

thanks!

Also tried to pass system variable to parameters, it works for cmdLine@2 task, but not for the container job.

```
parameters:
  - name: WORKING_DIRECTORY  
    default: '$(System.Default.WorkingDirectory)'
```

This will work:

```
     - task: CmdLine@2 
        inputs:
          script: |
            echo ${{ parameters.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}
```

But this won't work:

```
      container:
        image: ${{ variables.IMAGE_NAME}}
        options: --privileged 
        volumes:
          - ${{ parameters.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}:/mnt/data
```

Answer (score 0):

When Initialize containers task is running, the predefined variable `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` is not defined.

[image]

So, you can't use `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` when you are defining the options field of a container job in Azure DevOps. The value of this variable is expanded after the Initialize containers task.

You can use hard code path, `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` is `/home/vsts/work/1/s` for Ubuntu-hosted agent.

```
container:
  image: dockerhub.io/myregistry/myimg:latest
  options: --privileged --volume /home/vsts/work/1/s:/mnt/data:ro
steps:
  - script: printenv
```